# Applying animated ScaleTransform in code problem

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rendertransform

I am trying to find out why the code below does not seem to work. It does not give an error - it simply doesn't scale. It actually does seem to work if I change it as to my second code sample.
Anyone got any idea?

Thanks

```
public static void StartMouseEnterAnimation(Button button)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        button.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        button.RenderTransform = scale;

        DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        growAnimation.From = 1;
        growAnimation.To = 1.8;
        storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, scale);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

--- The following DOES work but I had to create a TransformGroup and reference this through a more complicated PropertyChain...

```
public static void StartMouseEnterAnimation(Button button)
    {    
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();            
        ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0, 1, 1);
        button.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
        TransformGroup myTransGroup = new TransformGroup();
        myTransGroup.Children.Add(scale);
        button.RenderTransform = myTransGroup;

        DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
        //growAnimation.From = 1;
        growAnimation.To = 1.1;
        storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

        DependencyProperty[] propertyChain = new DependencyProperty[]
        {
            Button.RenderTransformProperty, 
            TransformGroup.ChildrenProperty,
            ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty
        };
        string thePath = "(0).(1)[0].(2)";
        PropertyPath myPropertyPath = new PropertyPath(thePath, propertyChain);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, myPropertyPath);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, button);

        storyboard.Begin();
   }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by tweaking your first code sample like so:

```
public static void StartMouseEnterAnimation(Button button) {
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

    ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(1.0, 1.0);
    button.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
    button.RenderTransform = scale;

    DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
    growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
    growAnimation.From = 1;
    growAnimation.To = 1.8;
    storyboard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, button);

    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Instead of `new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty))`, I used `new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"))`, and I set the target of the storyboard to the button (not the scaleTransform itself).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to animate in two different directions on a ScaleTransform, when you have a transform group.  The path string shows which part is being animated.  Also, because Canvas is freezable, you have to `RegisterName`.  (I don't know what this means, but it is required)

```
        var storyBoard = new Storyboard();
        var group = new TransformGroup();
        var scale = new ScaleTransform(Zoom, Zoom);
        group.Children.Add(scale);
        group.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(_translateX,_translateY));
        MainCanvas.RenderTransform = group;

        RegisterName("MainCanvas",MainCanvas);

        var growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        growAnimation.From = _oldZoom;
        growAnimation.To = Zoom;
        storyBoard.Children.Add(growAnimation);

        var growAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        growAnimation2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        growAnimation2.From = _oldZoom;
        growAnimation2.To = Zoom;

        storyBoard.Children.Add(growAnimation2);

        string thePath = "(0).(1)[0].(2)"; // Not used - just to show the syntax


        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleX"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation2, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.Children[0].ScaleY"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(growAnimation, "MainCanvas");
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(growAnimation2,"MainCanvas");
        storyBoard.Begin(this);
```