# DoubleAnimation in ScaleTransform

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying, as an exhibition, to use a DoubleAnimation on the ScaleX and ScaleY properties of a ScaleTransform.  I have a rectangle (144x144) which I want to make rectangular over five seconds.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ScaleTransformTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="rect1" Width="144" Height="144" Fill="Aqua">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My C#:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ScaleTransform scaly = new ScaleTransform(1, 1);
    rect1.RenderTransform = scaly;

    Duration mytime = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

    DoubleAnimation danim1 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 1.5, mytime);
    DoubleAnimation danim2 = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0.5, mytime);
    sb.Children.Add(danim1);
    sb.Children.Add(danim2);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(danim1, scaly);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(danim1, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(danim2, scaly);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(danim2, new PropertyPath(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty));

    sb.Begin();
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this program, it does nothing.  The rectangle stays at 144x144.  If I do away with the animation, and just

```
ScaleTransform scaly = new ScaleTransform(1.5, 0.5);
rect1.RenderTransform = scaly;
```

it will elongate it instantly, no problem.  There is a problem elsewhere.  Any suggestions?  I have read the discussion at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/29220878/how-to-animate-tofrom-an.aspx in which someone seems to have gotten a pure-XAML version working, but the code is not shown there.

EDIT: At [Applying animated ScaleTransform in code problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131797/applying-animated-scaletransform-in-code-problem) it seems someone had a very similar problem, I am fine with using his method that worked, but what the heck is that `string thePath = "(0).(1)[0].(2)";` all about?  What are those numbers representing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the deal, this is a quote from MSDN's [Storyboards Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx) entry, in the section titled 'Where Can You Use a Storyboard?':

> A Storyboard  can be used to animate
>   dependency properties of animatable
>   classes (for more information about
>   what makes a class animatable, see the
>   Animation Overview). However, because
>   storyboarding is a framework-level
>   feature, the object must belong to the
>   NameScope  of a FrameworkElement  or a
>   FrameworkContentElement.

This got me thinking that the `ScaleTransform` object does not belong to the `NameScope` of any `FrameworkElement`. Even though the `Rectangle` is a `FrameworkElement`, since the `ScaleTransform` is not part of its logical children, but rather a value assigned to some other property (in this case the `RenderTransform` property).

To get around that you need to specify your target object and `PropertyPath` differently, thus:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(danim1, rect1);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(danim1, 
    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
```

Tried it and it works, even though I don't fully understand the quote from MSDN myself :-)

Comment: Actually, I get this error:

Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

Are you sure you copy/pasted your working code correctly?

Comment: Not sure, I actually found a copy/paste error which i corrected 17 minutes ago.

Comment: Still not working for you? I assure you, it does for me on .NET 4 with VS2010.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working for me using VS2008 with .NET 3.5 SP1.  I am still getting that error.