# How to animate image zoom change in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am building an image viewer.

I have created a functionality that when the user moves the slider, it changes the `ZoomLevel` property value. This subsequently zooms the image based on the value provided by the `ZoomLevel` property.

```
<Image 
    Name="image"
    Source="Sample1.jpg"
    Opacity="1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Stretch="None"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
    RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform 
                ScaleX="{Binding Path=ZoomLevel}" 
                ScaleY="{Binding Path=ZoomLevel}" />
            <TranslateTransform />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

I wish to be able to animate the zooming with a `DoubleAnimation`. Animation is supposed to start from the current zoom level and then get to the zoom specified in the bound `ZoomLevel` property. It would be great if someone could provide some help in XAML. Thanks!

#### Mouse wheel code:

```
private void border_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    int delta;

    delta = e.Delta;
    zoom(delta);
}

private void zoom(int delta)
{
    double zoomIncrement;

    //Different zoom levels at different zoom stages
    if (ZoomLevel > 2)
    {
        zoomIncrement = Math.Sign(delta) * 0.2;
    }
    else if (ZoomLevel >= 1 && ZoomLevel <= 2)
    {
        zoomIncrement = Math.Sign(delta) * 0.1;
    }
    else
    {
        zoomIncrement = Math.Sign(delta) * 0.06;
    }

    //Rounding zoom level to boundary values
    //Zooming is allowed from 10% to 600%
    if (ZoomLevel + zoomIncrement > 6)
    {
        ZoomLevel = 6;
    }
    else if (ZoomLevel + zoomIncrement < 0.1)
    {
        ZoomLevel = 0.1;
    }
    else
    {
        ZoomLevel += zoomIncrement;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you binding directly to the slider value? If so, what effect are you looking for? What is happening now?

Comment: Moving the slider changes the value of the `Zoom` property. Scrolling also changes the value of the `Zoom` property. Right now, the `Zoom` property is bound to the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of the image's ScaleTransform. Each change made by the scroll wheel or slider results in +/- 0.2 zoom increment.

Comment: For example: if the zoom is currently set at 80% scrolling up will change the zoom level to 82%. I want to animate that change.

Comment: Do you have the IsSnapToTickEnabled set true on the slider? Removing that would make it look smoother. If that's not a viable option i'll work something up for you now.

Comment: `IsSnapToTickEnabled` is not set to `true`. Zooming with slider is smooth, but zooming with scroll wheel isn't, because there's a 2% jump for each wheel movement. Reducing the zoom increment would result in smoother zooming, but then I'd have to scroll like mad just to make a small zoom level change :) The best option, I think, would be to animate that zoom level change. What do you think Scott?

Comment: I agree with you. Do it have to be XAML side? You are able to create storyboards with in C#?

Comment: It doesn't have to be XAML side, I just prefer that way. If you can help me with C# code-behind, I'd appreciate it very much :)

Comment: would you be able to post your mousewheel code?

Answer (score 2):

It is a little messy but try this.

```
namespace Zoom
{

    public partial class Window1
    {   
        public double ZoomLevel { get; set; }
        public double SlideLevel { get; set; }

        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ZoomLevel = 1.0;
            SlideLevel = 1.0;
            image.MouseWheel += image_MouseWheel;

        }

        private void image_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .1 : -.1;
            slider.Value = (SlideLevel + zoom);
        }

        private void ZoomImage(double zoom)
        {
            Storyboard storyboardh = new Storyboard();
            Storyboard storyboardv = new Storyboard();

            ScaleTransform scale = new ScaleTransform(ZoomLevel, ZoomLevel);
            image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            image.RenderTransform = scale;

            double startNum = ZoomLevel;
            double endNum = (ZoomLevel += zoom);

            if (endNum > 1.0)
            {
                endNum = 1.0;
                ZoomLevel = 1.0;
            }

            DoubleAnimation growAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
            growAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
            growAnimation.From = startNum;
            growAnimation.To = endNum;
            storyboardh.Children.Add(growAnimation);
            storyboardv.Children.Add(growAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleX"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, image);
            storyboardh.Begin();

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growAnimation, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.ScaleY"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(growAnimation, image);
            storyboardv.Begin();
        }

        private void slider_ValueChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
        {
            double zoomChange = (SlideLevel - slider.Value) * -1;
            SlideLevel = SlideLevel + zoomChange;

            ZoomImage(zoomChange);
        }
    }
}
```

I found this other [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131797/applying-animated-scaletransform-in-code-problem) to be quite helpful

Here is the current setup of XAML that I have as well.

```
    <Border MaxWidth="500"
        MaxHeight="500"
        Height="500"
        Width="500"
        Name="border">
    <Image
        Name="image"
        Source="picture1.png"
        Opacity="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Stretch="Fill"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"
        ClipToBounds="True">
    </Image>
    </Border>
    <Slider
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Margin="44,70,0,148"
        Name="slider"
        Width="24"
        Value="1.0"
        Minimum="0"
        Maximum="1.0"
        LargeChange="0.1"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
        TickFrequency="0.1"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="False"
        ValueChanged="slider_ValueChanged" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a ViewBox? You can bind the final width to any value you need, here's a quick sample:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="ZoomIn">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="ImageContainer">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="400"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Viewbox x:Name="ImageContainer" Width="200">
        <Image Source="http://images.wikia.com/lossimpson/es/images/a/a7/Homer_Simpson2.png"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```